# Show an element only when scrolling through certain divs

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, show-hide

I have a site with a lot of blank space (for visual reasons).  When a user scrolls through a blank space (usually 2000px or above marked by`.spacer`) I want another fixed div to show up.

The purpose is to make sure the user doesn't have to scroll through a lot of blank space.  The div that would "pop-up" or appear would simple have text pointing them to the navigation bar.  Then when the user **isn't** currently viewing `.spacer`, I want this div to disappear/hide.  How can I do this using jquery?  Thank you in advance for you time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example with multiple `.spacer` blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/ant_Ti/H8t6s/

Comment: Hey thanks!  Although I already did a make-shift version with CSS, **this is exactly what I was looking for**.  Thank you so very much!  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".spacer").hide(); // Hide your div by default
    $(".spacer").each(function() {
        var this = $(this);
        var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > topDistance ) { 
                this.show(); 
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Maybe this is not exactly what you want but can give you some ideas on how to achieve it.

Comment: What if `.spacer` are a few divs. You should iterrate

Comment: Ok `.spacer` appears after every content area to break them up.  I want `.lost` to show up when the user scrolls into a `.spacer`.  How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry its actually `.space` not "spacer"

Comment: `.lost` is fixed to the right of the screen about half way down.

Comment: @David well it's too hard for me if you're not posting any code. Btw, try to do it yourself since it'll help you to improve a lot of your coding skills :)

Comment: I've actually managed to pull this little trick off with CSS using z-indexes to achieve what I wanted!  Thank you all for the support though!  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @David Glad to hear that you can make it :)